# Unable to serialize both the forms at once using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have two form, first form input text, and file upload, the second form contains only text fields,
Here first is shown and the second form is hidden on the first and second form is shown and the first form is hidden, on submitting the second form, I want to combine two forms and submit the data by using ajax,

```
    <form id="data" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="first" value="Bob" />
    <input type="text" name="middle" value="James" />
    <input type="text" name="last" value="Smith" />
    <input name="image" type="file" />
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
    <form action="conn.php" method="POST" id="request-form2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="full_name2">
        <br/>
        <input type="text" name="last_name2">
        <br/>
        <input type="submit"  value="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```

Here is script, i have tried,

```
$('form#request-form2').click(function(event) {
                 event.preventDefault();
                    var formData2 = $('#data');
                    var formData = new FormData(formData2);
                    console.log(formData);
                        $.ajax({
                        url: 'conn.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: formData,
                        success: function (data) {
                            // console.log(data)
                        },
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false
                    });
            });
```

Comment: Do they need to be two separate `<form`> blocks?

Comment: @showdev, both are seperate form,

Comment: Yes, but does it need to be? Can't all the inputs be combined in one form?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, but why couldn't you just:

```
var formData=$('#data').serializeArray();
var formData2=$('#request-form2').serializeArray();
formData.push(formData2);
```

and include formData in your data option of your ajax call?